# Hashmap overwrites values. How to add multiple of the same key?

Tags: java

I know hashMap overwrites the kay, but I really need the same key to be provided for another value. What is also the issue is that in the postRequest further down, it needs to be set as a `Map` value.

So how can the below be fixed so that the body contains all the field and their values below as displayed in the table?

So we can't have `field3 = tree, cone`, it has to be field `3 = tree, field 3 = cone` or the service will fail.

```
    Example step:
       |field     |value                                       |
       |----------|--------------------------------------------|
       |field1    |shop                                        |
       |field2    |apple                                       |
       |field3    |tree                                        |
       |field3    |cone                                        |


    @Step("Example step: <table>")
    public void exampleStep(Table table) {
        Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();

           table.getTableRows().forEach(row -> {
            String value = row.getCell(VALUE);
            String field = row.getCell(FIELD);

                body.put(field, value);

        });

final String url = String.format("%s/service/%s", System.getenv(ENDPOINT), service);

new DBrequest(dataStore, url, HttpMethod.POST).postRequest(body);
```

Comment: No duplicate keys in `Map`s, it is that simple... You can think about a `Map<String, List<Object>>` or similar...

Comment: Guava has `Multimap<K,V>`, or do as deHaar said.

Comment: @dehaar I tried using the guava multimap but the issue was I need to some how iterate over the items to put it back to Map for the post request which is an inbuilt unirest function that relies on Map type as the entry. Can you show me in your answer how you would code with multi map and then convert back to Map to put through as post request so I can visually see how it works

Comment: @michael - see above

Comment: I haven't used Guava so far, that's why I cannot show you that... I can show you how to use a `Map<String, List<String>>` for example...

Comment: @dehaar yes please, would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Map<String, List<String>>` for example, you have to check if keys are present when you are inputting values, see this:

```
@Step("Example step: <table>")
public void exampleStep(Table table) {
    table.getTableRows().forEach(row -> {
        String value = row.getCell(VALUE);
        String field = row.getCell(FIELD);

        // you have to check if the key is already present
        if (body.containsKey(field)) {
            // if it is, you can simply add the new value to the present ones
            body.get(field).add(value);
        } else {
            // otherwise you have to create a new list
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
            // add the value to it
            values.add(value);
            // and then add the list of values along with the key to the map
            body.put(field, values);
        }
    });
}
```

You can iterate such a `Map` in several ways, one is this:

```
for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : body.entrySet()) {
    // print the key first
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":");
    // then iterate the value (which is a list)
    for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
        // and print each value of that list
        System.out.println("\t" + value);
        }
    };
}
```

**Please note:**
This is a simple example without any content and it doesn't handle any casting from `Object`.

Comment: Thanks DeHarr, been struggling on this for work for a while. Can I come back to you if I don't get this working and updfate the code just in case?

Comment: @BruceyBandit you can, but I cannot promise to answer quickly then... But keep in mind to provide minimal, working and reproducible examples. This time, I couldn't test anything of your code myself, that's why I provided an abstract example using `String`s only.

Comment: Thanks, I am having issues but I will see if it's because of the iteration that'scausing the issue